# Laravel API routing issue

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on Laravel 5 and I'm starting an API, so I just created a very simple route and controller just to test where the route will be hit. This is what I have in the `routes\api.php`

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'test', 'middleware' => ['guest']), function()
{
    Route::get('/', 'Aiapi\BaseAIApiController@index');

});
```

And the controller:

```
class BaseAIApiController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return 'HI';
    }
}
```

In my `Http\Kernel.php`, this is how the guest middleware is declared inside the `$routeMiddleware` variable: `'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,` and this is the content of the `handle` method (I commented the if block and same thing happens):

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        return redirect('/home');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

When I execute `php artisan route:list` I see this route there, I also executed `php artisan route:clear`
but when I hit `/api/test/`I get redirected to the home page of the website. Here is the content of the `.htaccess` inside the `public` folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule thumb/([[:alnum:]]+)\/(.*) thumbnail/?src=$2&params=$1 [QSA,L,NC]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

I tried removing the line block with the `301 redirect` but it does the same thing. What AM I doing wrong here? I've been trying answers of similar questions on StackOverflow and so far none worked for me.

Thanks for any help

Comment: you get redirected to '/home' or '/' ?

Comment: @lagbox I get redirected to '/fr'. It's a multi language site. The web routes have the App:getLocale() as prefix

Comment: I think you're being redirected because you're logged in, try on a private browser window

Comment: @Saly3301same thing. I tried both of these addresses as well: /api/test and /api/test/. All of them redirect me to the home

Comment: Edit the question and add your guest middleware or `Http\Kernel.php`

Comment: @Saly3301 just did! I commented the redirect in the middleware and nothing changes

Comment: Are you authenticated? The RouteServiceProvider adds the api routes to the API middleware. If you remove the middleware here does the redirect stop? Sorry if I misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The way I'm describing my routes and my controller should work perfectly. I figured out that in this application I'm working on has a Language provider that basically forces all the routes to start with `en`, `fr` or `admin`.

This is was the cause of the problem I was having